# How do I pre-generate a Minecraft bedrock world

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am looking for a easy script that can teleport me across my Minecraft Bedrock Edition world so I can generate the chunks without causing lag as people explore my server. Please make sure it works for the Bedrock Edition.

Comment: Are you looking for a script for like a servers, or your question is tagged commands so are you looking for a command?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way that I know of to generate chunks before someone has arrived in that location; the easiest way would be to teleport everyone to all the locations you need generated, which would be quickest done through functions if you're looking for commands. Render distance is 196 blocks (12 chunks) in each direction. To maximize each teleport to load, it would start at, for example 0, 0, then teleport to 0, 392 to load the chunks.